# Call a module from a phtml

Tags: magento-1.9

How I can call a module that I created from a phtml ?.

It can be called as a static block, but I have no idea how it can call its own module from a .phtml

Comment: Can you provide the code that you used to create the extension?

Comment: Can you explain some more what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('my_static_block_name')->toHtml();
```

Or

```
<?php print $this->getLayout()
                 ->createBlock("catalog/product_view")
                 ->setTemplate("catalog/product/view/addto.phtml")
                 ->toHtml(); ?>
```

or

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock(‘core/template’)->setTemplate(‘templateFolder/yourtemplate.phtml’)->toHtml(); ?>
```

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: Thank you denish, i solved with:


$this->getLayout()->createBlock(‘core/template’)->setTemplate(‘templateFolder/yourtemplate.phtml’)->toHtml(); ?>

Answer (score 2):

> Call static block in your module .phtml bellow way :

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your_block_identifier')->toHtml(); ?>
```

**For eg.** I have created static block in admin side `Contact Information` and it is identifier `contact_information` then my static block call in my header.phtm file like this way:

```
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('contact_information')->toHtml(); ?>
```

> Call phtml file in module app/design/frontend/{your_package}/{your_theme}/layout/{your_layout_file}.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <yourmodule_yourcontroller_youraction>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="yourmodule/yourblock" name="yourblock" template="yourmodule/yourphtml.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </yourmodule_yourcontroller_youraction>
</layout>
```

**OR**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <yourmodule_yourcontroller_youraction>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="yourblock_name" template="yourmodule/yourphtml.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </yourmodule_yourcontroller_youraction>
</layout>
```

**For eg**. My module name : `uploadfile`, Controller Name : `index` & Action Name : `index` ,Block name : `temp` and phtm file name : `temp.phtml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
    </default>
    <uploadfile_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="uploadfile/temp" name="temp.file" template="uploadfile/temp.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </uploadfile_index_index>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have my static block and i print in my static block this:

> {{blocktype="holamundo/saludador " name="holamundo_saludador" template="holamundo/holamundo.phtml"}

The id of my static block is saludador.
Well, now in my `header.phtml` i call my static block with this:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('saludador')->toHtml(); ?>
```

but in the position so i write these, in the browser print this:

> {{block type="holamundo/saludador" name="holamundo_saludador" template="holamundo/holamundo.phtml"}

This is my layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<holamundo_index_index>
<reference name="content">
<block type="holamundo/holamundo" name="holamundo" template="holamundo/holamundo.phtml" />
</reference>
</holamundo_index_index>

<holamundo_index_saludar>
<reference name="content">
<block type="holamundo/holamundo" name="holamundo" template="holamundo/holamundo.phtml"/>
</reference>
</holamundo_index_saludar>
</layout>
```